# Overthrow and throw-by

Tags: cricket, terminology

The two terms are very popular in my locality. According to my teacher,

> **overthrow:** is when fielder near the pitch misses throw from fielder at far 
>    off in field.

He defined "throw-by" as the event when "batsman has not touched the ball with his bat or gloves or any part of his body, he attempts run, fielder throws ball but misses run out"

Surprisingly, I found no mention of "throw-by" on the internet or in the laws as my teacher said.

Did he confuse "throw-by" with another popular terminology? Or is there really some "throw-by" phenomenon, conspicuously absent from the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much I understand the context, your teacher probably wants the differentiate a bye run and a normal run in the context of overthrow. These two can also be looked into as two entirely different context. Whatever comes off the bat is normal run and whatever does not come off the bat are extra run - in our context a bye run. On the other hand overthrow is any run conceded by the fielding team after the event of ***throw*** by the fielders, as you described correctly above. The term, according to my knowledge, is **not any official term**, but it is ***widely used*** to convey the sense of **Bye + Overthrow** in different parts of India.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

This term is not known to a group of cricket enthusiasts and fans, and a Google search using various parameters relating to cricket wicketkeepers and overthrows did not find any results with the phrase.

I conclude that this term specifically for an overthrow by the wicketkeeper is not common in the world and probably limited to a small region or regions.